# Solve Recurrence Equation: $T(n)=T(n−4)+n^2$

Tags: solution-verification, asymptotics, recurrence-relations

I'm trying to practice recurrence equations, so I'm trying to solve this typology by unfolding method.
I was wondering if what I write below was correct and obviously the result:

$T(n) = n^2 + T(n-4) = n^2 + [n^2 + T(n - 8)] = n^2 + n^2 +[n^2 + T(n-12)] = n^2 + n^2 + n^2 + [n^2 + T(n-16)] = ...$

In general we can say that $T(n)$ is done in the following way:

$$T(n) = \sum_{i=0}^{\frac{n-5}{4}} n^2 + T(n-(4+4i))$$

Note that the summation takes that form because $T(n-(4+4i)) = T(1) = 1$ when $( −(4+4) ) = 1$ which occurs for $i = \frac{n-5}{4}$

So it would be more correct to write T(n) as follows:

$$T(n) = \sum_{i=0}^{\frac{n-5}{4}} n^2  + 1 $$

At this point we leave out the constant 1 (which asymptotically is irrelevant) and focus on the summation :

$$T(n) = \sum_{i=0}^{\frac{n-5}{4}} n^2 = n^2\sum_{i=0}^{\frac{n-5}{4}} 1 = n^2 ( \frac{n-5}{4} +1) = O(n^3)$$

So overall we can say that :

$$T(n) = O(n^3)$$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/info

Comment: Is $T(1)=1$ given? If so, you should edit your post to make this explicit. Else, you should not assume it.

Comment: There may be no integer $i$ such that $i = \frac{n-5}4.$ Actually, such an $i$ exists iff $n\equiv1\bmod4.$

Comment: What do you mean by "solve this typology"? What are you trying to do? Which "result" are you aiming at? An explicit formula for $T(n)$ or just an asymptotic estimate?

Comment: $T(n-4)=n^2 + T(n - 8)$ on the first line is already wrong, instead $T(n-4)=(n-4)^2 + T(n - 8)$, similarly for subsequent terms.

Comment: Hint.

Making $n=4m$ we have

$$
T(4m)=T(4(m-1))+(4m)^2
$$

This recurrence can be recast as

$$
R(m) = R(m-1) + (4m)^2
$$

with solution

$$
R(m) = c_0 + 16\sum_{k=1}^n k^2
$$

etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $n^2 + T(n-4) = n^2 + [\color{red}{n^2} + T(n - 8)]$

1. The first line is wrong. Note that $T(n-4)=\color{red}{(n-4)^2}+T(n-8)$

> In general we can say that $T(n)$ is done in the following way:
> $$T(n) = \sum_{i=0}^{\frac{n-5}{4}} n^2 + T(n-(4+4i))$$

2. The second line is also wrong. How do you know $\frac{n-5}4$ is an integer? For example, if $n=6$, then $\frac{n-5}4=\frac14$, which doesn't make sense.
3. What is your initial condition?

In general, we can solve it by setting $n=4k, n=4k+1, n=4k+2, n=4k+3$ and solve each case separately. Since the @Cesareo's comment has shown the $n=4k$ case, I will show the $n=4k+1$ case. The rest two cases can be solved similarly. Now, let $n=4k+1$ and $P_k=T(4k+1)$, we get

$T(4k+1)=T(4k-3)+(4k+1)^2\Longleftrightarrow P_k=P_{{k-1}}+16k^2+8k+1$

Take the sum

$$\sum_{m=1}^k P_m-P_{{m-1}}=\sum_{m=1}^k16m^2+8m+1\Longrightarrow P_k-P_0=\frac83k(k+1)(2k+1)+4k(k+1)+k$$

Simplify and we get

$$P_k=P_0+\frac13 k\cdot ( 16 k^2 + 36 k+23 )$$

Therefore,

$$\boxed{T(4k+1)=\frac{16}3 k^3 + 12 k^2+\frac{23}3k +T_1}$$

The rest two cases $T(4k+2)$ and $T(4k+3)$ can be solved similarly.